# jQuery fadeIn() "glitch" or "sudden switch" in multiple browsers

Tags: jquery, fonts, opacity, fadein

I'm calling a simple fadeIn() on a specific element within a div that is initially hidden.

JavaScript:

```
$("#enclosingdiv").css({visibility: "visible"});
$("#element").fadeIn(1500);
```

The problem is that for the duration of the fading animation, the rendering makes the text appear bolder or in a different font. When the animation is complete it reverts to the original font/font-weight, hence the "glitch" or "sudden switch". I've encountered this issue in both Chrome and IE 8 and also while implementing the animate(opacity) method which animated the opacity from 0 to 100 (essentially the same effect as fadeIn()).

I've done a good amount of research and have tried a multitude of solutions:

1. Disabled IE's filter (even though the issue is not IE specific).
2. Added a background to the element being animated.
3. Set -webkit-font-smoothing to antialiased (with no apparent effect).
4. Tried a fadeTo(0.99) which only suspends the text in the unknown or bold font which does not resemble the original font.

By the way I'm running Windows XP.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Txk7/34/

Comment: If it happens in multiple browsers, it's likely not a .. anyway, post a *minimal* test-case (complete minimal code here *and* in a jsfiddle) ..

Comment: do you have ClearType turned on?  what happens if you toggle it?

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem (we need to see your CSS/HTML too).  Older versions of IE are notorious for ugly opacity fading of some text fonts.  In some cases, selecting a different font will make the problem go away.  But, I've never seen this issue on Chrome so we'd need to see it in the jsFiddle.

Comment: @jfriend00 [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2Txk7/). I've renamed the variables and id's as well as omitted some content for confidentiality reasons. Dependency is satisfied to my knowledge.

Comment: By jsFiddle, I meant something that actually works and illustrates the issue your are asking about.  I can't figure out how to make your jsFiddle actually do anything.  All the content of the page is hidden and the code calls functions that aren't present.  This does not illustrate the issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry I was actually not aware that jsFiddle could run animations, I was posting the jsFiddle for the sake of an organized view and not so much the ability to run it. I've updated the link and have animation running on load instead of an onClick event. It displays the issue. [Updated jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2Txk7/31/)

Comment: @pst [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Txk7/34/)

Comment: @Eevee I've tried toggling ClearType with no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered a workaround that seems to work pretty well. However it doesn't solve the underlying issue with fadeIn() that's causing the "glitch" but it provides an alternative which I've decided to implement until someone can solve the original problem.

Basically I applied an overlay of an image that matches the background over top of the element that needed faded in using the z-index property. So instead of having the text fade in, I had the image which had a higher z-index implement fadeOut() to reveal the underlying text. See below:

```
#background {
position: absolute;
background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
#text {
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
top: 100px;
z-index: 2;
}

$("#background").fadeOut(1500);
```

It appears that most browsers do a much better job handling the fading or opacity of graphics when compared to the same functions being performed on text.

Again, I don't believe it's the ideal solution but one that will accomplish the same result.

Comment: I'd say this workaround is currently the best, most reliable way of achieving your desired end result. Glad you got it worked out.